# how to send query param in nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am writing a proxy for my site and need that all the query param will be pass to the proxy URL. For example, I want that http://ngnix-server/api?qp1=ok&qp2=111 will be mapped to a target server http://172.31.93.233/proxy.php?qp1=ok&qp2=111

This is what i have write in the configuration file:

```
location /api {
   rewrite ^/(.+)$ ?q=$1
     proxy_pass http://172.31.93.233/proxy.php;
 }
```

Can someone point out where I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you remove the `rewrite` statement, the query string should pass through by default.

Comment: It not looks like this actually when i removed the rewrite and call api, it given me 502 bad gateway error.